# How to call other service API methods from node.js

Tags: node.js

In my application i need to use twillio module API to send and receive sms.But i dont know how to call other API methods in node.js.Now im using node.js with socketstream.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [request](https://npmjs.org/package/request) module, the documentation has a lot of great examples how to call REST API methods.

And for Twilio you can read this guide "[Getting Started with Twilio and Node.js](http://www.twilio.com/blog/2011/05/getting-started-with-twilio-and-node-js.html)" and use the [twilio](https://npmjs.org/package/twilio) module.

Comment: hi i need one help from you.

Comment: Just ask here, edit your question or create a new one if isn't related.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have an API call that is already working with curl, something like:

> curl -X POST -H "Token:SecurityToken"
>   -H "Content-Type: application/json" 
>   https://yourURL.com
>   -d '{"records":[{"value":"Testing the API Function"}]}'

You will need to first install proper modules for your node.js:

```
npm install request
```

Then you will need to create a js file with the following content:

```
var Request = require("request");

// Preparing API CAll with Post Action and its arguments
Request.post({
    "headers": { "content-type": "application/json" ,"Token":"SecurityToken" },
    "url": "YourURL.com",
    "body": JSON.stringify({"records":[{"value":"Testing the API Function"}]})
}, (error, response, body) => {
    if(error) {
        return console.dir(error);
    }
    // console.log(response);
    console.dir(JSON.parse(body));
});
```